# HikariCP + mariadb-java-client configuration fails

Tags: mysql, hikaricp

I try to move from `mysql-java-client` to `mariadb-java-client`. I use `HikariCP` pool and I use default MySQL configuration provide from HikariCP website.

If I use default mysql client, works fine, but with mariadb I need to remove this params:

```
<!-- Works with both clients -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider</property>

<!-- Works with mysql-java-client, not with mariadb-java-client -->
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">true</property>
```

I don't known if I need to specified these params or are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [not currently supported](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/CONJ-22) by the MariaDB JDBC driver.

Comment: You can leave those options off, at a slight performance hit.